# Friendly_id PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I try to use Friendly_id but I have an error just for one model.

track model :

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord 
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :track_name, use: :slugged
  has_many :pois
```

poi model :

```
class Poi < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_and_city, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :track
```

I need to have a pois list by track

In my pois_controller :

```
def index
  @pois = Poi.all
  @pois = Poi.where("track_id = ?", params[:track_id])
```

In my routes :

```
 resources :tracks, only:[], :shallow => true  do
   resources :pois
 end
```

But I want to go to my pois_index, the params for track_id is a string (the slug), not an integer.

What can I do ?

Comment: If you need the `track_id` to be an integer, why not just convert it? `params[:track_id].to_i`. Also, you don't need the `.all` query.

Comment: Because in params I have the track slug and not the track id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails bad idea to interpolate params into raw SQL. That is why you have an error with wrong syntax. In this case you should use ActiveRecord.

```
Poi.where(track_id: params[:track_id])
```

When you interpolate params to sql you should prevent sql injection. ActiveRecord do it automatically.

Comment: Maybe... but the problem it's not here. I get the slug not the id.

  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "track_id"=>"variante"}
  Poi Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "pois".* FROM "pois" WHERE "pois"."track_id" = $1  [["track_id", 0]]

Comment: I see rails console and when I try `User.where('id = ?', 'asd')` I have error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "asd"` When I do `User.where(id: 'asd')` I have `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` So your error said about wrong parameter interpolation.

Comment: It's true. Thks I do not have any more this error but my list stay empty. :(

Comment: You can find pois by track slug. If find tracks and then find pois.
`tracks = Track.friendly.find(params[:track_id]); @pois = Poi.where(track_id: tracks)` according to the [guide](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) of FriendlyId

Comment: Friendly gem just add `friendly.find` method for ActiveRelation or ActiveRecord. So you can use only this method for finding by slug and then use ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem for your help ;) All work fine now.